# Converting zend_rest's output to json

Tags: zend-rest

I am developing a REST api in joomla using Zend_Rest. As Zend components can be decoupled, I am not using the whole Zend framework in my joomla installation but rather the Zend_Loader and the Zend_Rest in creating my application.

The main issue is - due to requirements, I need to have the output data the server spits out in json format as opposed to the xml tree this component spits out.

If i were using the whole framework, from what I gather a contextSwitch helper would have just done the easy porting for me.

So how then do I port these outputs into Json knowing fully well I dont have the Controller Action in place and I am not developing within the ZF.

I will appreciate any help regarding this. Thanks